# Design for a calculator service

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have class called Calculator which invokes a service called **CalculatorService** to perform certain arithmetic operations.

```
public class Calculator {

   @Autowired
    CalculatorService calculatorService;

    @GET
    @Path("/add/{x}/{y}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response add(@PathParam("x") int x, @PathParam("y") int y) {
        Double addR=calculatorService.add(x, y);
        Result r = new Result();
        r.setResult(addR);
        return Response.ok(r).build();
    }
}
```

Instead of creating a new object of class Result and updating result here, I want to do it in a cleaner way, something like below.

```
calculatorService.add(x, y).result();
```

This will return a Result class object which will eventually converted to JSON response and returned.
Result class may have some more property like num1, num2, timeTakenByCalculation etc.

I thought to use builder pattern using some helper class but could not figure out how to achieve it.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking. Maybe you just want a helper method for wrapping the result into an OK response to get those three lines out of each of the operation methods? Like `return createOkResponse(calculatorService.add(x, y));`?

Comment: Thanks Alex, Since Response.ok().build is a part of Jersy API so I don't worry about. I don't want to create new instance of Result with populated result and other values. So I want to invoke one more method on calculatorservice API which will generate Result object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The intent of the Builder design pattern is to separate the
>   construction of a complex object from its representation. By doing so,
>   the same construction process can create **different
>   representations.**

You don't want/need different representations of your JSON response, so no need to apply Build Pattern.

Why not simply:

```
public interface CalculatorService {
  Result calculate(x, y); 
}
```

and

```
public class ResultJSONConverter {
  public JSONResponse convert(Result result);   
}
```

You'd use them like this:

```
JSONResponse response = new ResultJSONConverter().convert(calculatorService.calculate(x,y));
```

Comment: Thanks Mik, I thought to use this approach but here I don't want to change behavior of calculate service. Calculate Service should do only arithmetic operation and return calculated return.You can think like, I am using a third party library which is injected using spring and just returning a calculated result.

Comment: In my case, calculatorService only does arithmetic operation and returns it. Same as yours. I don't think you really figured out my solution ;)